# Php preg_match to capture only specific phrases

Tags: php, regex

Example string:

```
$string = 'text text text text {capture this1, this2} text text text text';
```

I want to use `preg_match`, to get only these `this1`, and `this2` in an array and nothing else.

I was trying something like so:

```
$array = array();
$reg = '/\{capture.*\}/'; //this needs changing
preg_match($reg, $string, $array);
var_dump($array);
```

This captures `{capture this1, this2}`. How do i exclude the '{' sign from regex? I was trying something like `.!\{` but it gave me errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you need only `capture this1, this2` ?

Comment: no, i need `this1` and `this2`, array would look like so `array('this1', 'this2')`.

Comment: Doing it in one expression `{capture\s*\K[^,{}]+(?=[^}]*})|\G(?<!^),\s*\K[^,{}]+(?=[^}]*})`, it's quite a pain to explain it. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mE9eO4) :)

Comment: Thanks HamZa, seems like it returns what i need, i will now examine it:) thank you

Comment: @HamZa are you a wizard?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following regex:

```
/\{(capture[^}]*)\}/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '~(?:{capture |\G(?!\A), )\K[^,}]+(?=(})?)~';
$data = 'text text text {capture this1, this2} text text';
$tmp = array();

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($matches as $m) {
        $tmp[] = $m[0];
        if (isset($m[1])) {
            $result = $tmp;
            break; 
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

This pattern avoid to use this lookahead `(?=[^}]*})` to check the closing curly bracket presence and use `(?=(})?)` that is faster to test. if the capture group exists, you know that the brackets are closed.

However I think that Shankar Damodaran method is more simple (and possibly more efficient).